# Call retrofit api for post data

Tags: java, php, android-studio

I want to connect my project calling the database connector with retrofit, but I always get a "gagal" response in the else(fail) section, can anyone correct the code I made?
Note : In the PHP section, when I tested using Postman, the data was able to be posted.

public class incomingItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String item,quantity;

```
TextInputEditText etNama;
TextInputEditText etQuantity;
TextInputEditText etTanggal;
Button button;
private ResponseItemDatang respon;

private ModelItemDatang dataItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_item);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("FORM BARANG");

    //etNama
    etNama = findViewById(R.id.NamaItemET);
    //etQuantity
    etQuantity = findViewById(R.id.QuantityItemET);

    //button + panggilAPI
    button = findViewById(R.id.simpan);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAPI();
        }
    });
    //DatePicker
    etTanggal = findViewById(R.id.Date);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    etTanggal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(incomingItemActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    month = month + 1;
                    String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                    etTanggal.setText(date);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}

private void setAPI() {
    APInterface apInterface = APIclient.getAPIclient().create(APInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseItemDatang> call  = apInterface.tambahItem(item,quantity);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseItemDatang>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseItemDatang> call, Response<ResponseItemDatang> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                ResponseItemDatang itemDatang = response.body();
                etNama.setText(itemDatang.getItem());
                etQuantity.setText(itemDatang.getQuantity());

                Intent intent = new Intent(incomingItemActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss");
                try {
                    Date Time = dateFormat.parse(respon.getTanggal());
                    etTanggal.setText(dataItem.getDate().substring(11, 16) + "|" + dateFormat.format(Time));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(incomingItemActivity.this, "gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseItemDatang> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What is a "gagal" response? How is this problem related to PHP or Android Studio?

Comment: I added a toast to the else logic section by displaying the words "gagal" which means failure in English and the "gagal" toast section is what appears when I try to post data

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem